# Is it a proper prior specification for estimating MCMCglmm?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior

I am working with my doctoral thesis and trying to fit a generalized linear mixed effects model by using ‘MCMCglmm’ package in R. I have repeatedly read Jarrod's helpful tutorial materials. However, there are still some problems about the priors specification I failed to figure out.

In my research, the dependent variable is the number of people participating in household energy conservation program (count outcome). It has been repeatedly measured for each day over approximately three years for each of 360 communities (the data are thus quite big and n = 371, 520). In addition, these communities are located at different districts (a total of 90 districts). Thus, the longitudinal daily count data are nested within communities within districts. My research aims to investigate which factors would influence the (daily) number of participants in such program. The basic model is (over-dispersed) Poisson model:

```
#give the priors
prior.poi <- list(R = list(V = diag(1), nu = 0.002, n=0, fix=1),
G = list(
G1=list(V = diag(3)*0.02, nu =4),
G2=list(V=diag(3)*0.02, nu=4)
))

#fit the model
model.poi <- MCMCglmm(y ~ 1 + t + x + x:t + t2 + t3 + t4 + c1 + c2 + c3 + d1 + d2 + d3,
random = ~ us(1 + t + x):no_c + us(1 + t + x):no_d,
rcov = ~idh(1):units,
family = "poisson",
data = dat.big,
prior = prior.poi,
burnin = 15000, nitt = 65000, thin = 50)
```

In the fixed effects part, ‘y’ is the count outcome; ‘t’ measures time in elapsed days since the start of the program; ‘x’ is another behavior intervention implemented for some communities. ‘t2 ~ t4’ are other time-variant factors (i.e. dummies measuring weekend and public holiday, and log term of average daily temperature); ‘c1 ~ c3’, and ‘d1 ~ d3’ measure the community and district-level characteristics respectively, which are time-invariant variables (e.g. total population, area size). In the random effects part, ‘no_c’ and ‘no_d’ are the record number of each community and district.

Since there are many excess zeros in my data, so I further run a hurdle (over-dispersed) Poisson model, as follows.

```
#give the priors
prior.hp <- list(R = list(V = diag(2), nu = 0.002, n=0, fix=1),  
G = list(
G1=list(V = diag(6)*0.02, nu =7),
G2=list(V=diag(6)*0.02, nu=7)
)
)

#fit the model
model.hp <- MCMCglmm(y ~ -1 + trait + trait:t + trait:x + trait:x:t + trait:t2 + trait:t3 + trait:t4 + trait:c1 + trait:c2 + trait:c3 + trait:d1 + trait:d2 + trait:d3, 
random = ~ us(trait + trait:t + trait:x):no_c + us(trait + trait:t + trait:x):no_d, 
rcov = ~idh(trait):units,
family = "hupoisson", 
data = dat.big, 
prior = prior.hp, 
burnin = 15000, nitt = 65000, thin = 50, 
pr = T, pl = T)
```

Both OD and hurdle Poisson models could work well only when ‘fix = 1’ was added into the R- structure of the prior specification. When it was removed from the priors, both models would return the error message:

> “Mixed model equations singular: use a (stronger) prior”

, and stop running. This error would not disappear regardless of whether parameter expansions were used in the G-structure (that is, alpha.mu=rep(0, 3), alpha.V=diag(3)*25^2 for OD Poisson model, and alpha.mu=rep(0, 6), alpha.V=diag(6)*25^2 for hurdle model) or not, either whether other elements in R-structure were removed/adjusted or not.

In hurdle Poisson model, since the covariance matrix for zero-alteration process cannot be estimated, ‘fix = 2’ should be used in R-structure rather than “fix = 1”. However, the model could not run well unless the residual variance for the zero-truncated Poisson process is fixed at 1, as described above. My question is that is it appropriate to fix the residual variance for both zero-alteration and Poisson processes at 1 in the R-structure? Is it too ‘informative’ for my model estimation? Are there any other priors I can take to make the model run well? Any idea about these questions will be appreciated.